# Compute mean before (and after) specific date

Tags: pandas, group-by, time-series, panel, mean

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

| id | year | dummy | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2010 | 0 | 25 |
| A | 2011 | 0 | 35 |
| A | 2012 | 1 | 21 |
| A | 2013 | 1 | 36 |
| A | 2014 | 1 | 45 |
| B | 2009 | 0 | 17 |
| B | 2010 | 1 | 27 |
| C | 2003 | 0 | 13 |
| C | 2004 | 0 | 45 |
| C | 2005 | 1 | NaN |

I must compute the mean of variable for each id for all dummy = 0 and dummy = 1. [My dummy =1 for each id after a specific year. So I basically need the mean of variable before and after a specific year.]

**EDIT:**
The results should look something like this:

| id | dummy | mean(variable) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 30 |
| A | 1 | 34 |
| B | 0 | 17 |
| B | 1 | 27 |
| C | 0 | 29 |
| C | 1 | NaN |

Can anyone assist?

Thank you and best!

Comment: `df[df['year'].between(2010, 2012)].groupby(['id','dummy'])['variable'].mean()`?

Comment: how the expected result will look like?